# Struts Plugin for Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, struts

I'm looking for a Struts 1.x plugin for Eclipse Indigo. I've looked on the net, but can't seem to find anything that's easy to setup. I've been using NetBeans till date, and it's got a nice support for struts, as in automatically updating the struts-config.xml file.

I'm not looking for a GUI-based plugin, just something that takes care of the stuff I need to do manually in struts-config.xml, web.xml like taglib imports, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AmaterasIDE](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/amateraside) comprises StrutsIDE that could be exactly what you're looking for ...